# Server Error in '/' Application. when deployed ServiceStack to Virtual Folder

Tags: c#, servicestack, iis-10

I'm trying to deploy a ServiceStack API to IIS7 in a Virtual Directory but I'm  getting this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9rjg.png)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Also dump file could show the real physical path that application are trying to access. What about host it in sub-application or root folder?

Comment: @JokiesDing I have added pictures

Answer (score 1):

This is a runtime dll loading issue where the .NET Runtime is unable to load `ServiceStack.dll`.

Some possible causes is due to having "dirty .dll's" i.e. ServiceStack packages with different versions. Make sure all ServiceStack NuGet packages have the same version, e.g. v5.9. After upgrading all NuGet packages in the same version, close your IDE, delete your `/packages` folder & reload your solution, then check all ServiceStack packages have the same version, if they contain different versions you still have a project referencing an older package.

Another issue I can think of that may prevent .dll's loading is if trying to load it in a deprecated [partial/medium trust environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/msp-n-p/ff648344(v=pandp.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN). ServiceStack requires full trust.

Other than that, check the bin folder of the deployed site to make sure it's deployed all .dll's.

Comment: I have forgot to write that the problems occures when I have deployet it to an Virtual Directory on IIS server

Answer (score 1):

Convertet the virtual directory to an Application